# JQuery selector change every 3 item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working with PHP loops and creating multiple `li` in one `ul`. 
The problem is, that I need to show every fourth `li` when I click on one of the three previous `li`.

At the moment It only works with the first previous `li` with this:

```
  $('.last_news li').on('click', function(){

      $('+ .actu_details',this).toggleClass('expend');

  });
```

Anyone got some clues

```js
$('.last_news li').on('click', function() {

  $('+ .actu_details', this).toggleClass('expend');

});
```

```css
last_news {
  padding: 35px
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}

li:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

li:nth-of-type(4n+7) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

li.actu_details {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}

li.actu_details.expend {
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="last_news">
  <div class="contenu_grid">
    <ul>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="actu_details">
        Detail
      </li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="actu_details">
        Detail
      </li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="actu_details">
        Detail
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: use `.eq(3)` to get the 4th element of a DOM element array - as in `$('li').eq(3)`

Comment: You can try with $('li:nth-child(3)') too

Comment: Using your syntax, it would be: `$('~ .actu_details',this).first().toggleClass('expend');` [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfdLo1mw/6/) BUT Satpal's answer is better regarding readability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nextAll()` to target following sibling `actu_details` element then use `:first`/`:eq(0)`/`.eq(0)`/`.first()` to target first `li`

```
$('.last_news li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).nextAll('.actu_details:first').toggleClass('expend');
    //$(this).nextAll('.actu_details').eq(0).toggleClass('expend');
});
```

```js
 $('.last_news li').on('click', function() {
   $(this).nextAll('.actu_details:first').toggleClass('expend');
 });
```

```css
.last_news {
  padding: 35px
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}

li:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

li:nth-of-type(4n+7) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

li.actu_details {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}

li.actu_details.expend {
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="last_news">
  <div class="contenu_grid">
    <ul>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="actu_details">
        Detail
      </li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="actu_details">
        Detail
      </li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="une_actu">Test</li>
      <li class="actu_details">
        Detail
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upLxd3tn/)